# Confusion with super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, super

Override to_xml.

What are the difference between these codes. Can someone explain it with proper example ?

1.

```
def to_xml(options = {})
  options.merge!(:methods  => [ :murm_case_name, :murm_type_name ])
  super
end
```

2.

```
def to_xml(options = {})
  super
  options.merge!(:methods  => [ :murm_case_name, :murm_type_name ])
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** `super` behaves in unexpected ways, and variables matter, not just objects.

When `super` is called, it's not called with the object that was passed in.

It's called with the variable that is called `options` at the time of the call. For example, with the following code:

```
class Parent
  def to_xml(options)
    puts "#{self.class.inspect} Options: #{options.inspect}"
  end
end

class OriginalChild < Parent
  def to_xml(options)
    options.merge!(:methods  => [ :murm_case_name, :murm_type_name ])
    super
  end
end

class SecondChild < Parent
  def to_xml(options)
    options = 42
    super
  end
end

begin
  parent_options, original_child_options, second_child_options = [{}, {}, {}]
  Parent.new.to_xml(parent_options)
  puts "Parent options after method called: #{parent_options.inspect}"
  puts
  OriginalChild.new.to_xml(original_child_options)
  puts "Original child options after method called: #{original_child_options.inspect}"
  puts
  second_child_options = {}
  SecondChild.new.to_xml(second_child_options)
  puts "Second child options after method called: #{second_child_options.inspect}"
  puts
end
```

Which produces the output

```
Parent Options: {}
Parent options after method called: {}

OriginalChild Options: {:methods=>[:murm_case_name, :murm_type_name]}
Original child options after method called: {:methods=>[:murm_case_name, :murm_type_name]}

SecondChild Options: 42
Second child options after method called: {}
```

You can see that with `SecondChild` the super method is called with the variable `options` which refers to a `Fixnum` of value `42`, not with the object that was originally referred to by `options`.

With using `options.merge!`, you'd modify the hash object that was passed to you, which means that the object referred to by the variable `original_child_options` is now modified, as can be seen in the `Original child options after method called: {:methods=>[:murm_case_name, :murm_type_name]}` line.

(Note: I changed `options` to 42 in SecondChild, rather than call `Hash#merge`, because I wanted to show it wasn't merely a case of side effects on an object)

Comment: Thanks for nice example. If i will write super before options in OriginChild and SecondChild than what is the difference.

Comment: @Krunal: You can modify the code above, and then re-run it in irb (the Interactive Ruby Shell). You've heard of irb, right?

Answer (score 2):

the first return the result of super call. So it's like you never to something in your case.

The second call super before your change and change options after.

I suppose you really want :

```
def to_xml(options = {})
  super(options.merge!(:methods  => [ :murm_case_name, :murm_type_name ]))
end
```

Comment: You don't need `!` in that case.

Comment: -1 The first line in scenario 1 would modify the object referred to by the variable `options`, so how would it be "you never [do] something"?